# SQL Statement Inside A PHP Echo, Inside HTML Tag

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using mySQL, and I have a SQL statement assigned to a variable in PHP. Later, I have an HTML `<p>` element where I want to call the SQL statement and insert the result into the string. So, if there's one item in `AppsToBeApproved`, the resulting `<p>` content should read "You have 1 new applications."

"appID" is the auto-incrementing primary key for each item

```
<?php
$newAppsCount = "COUNT(appID) FROM AppsToBeApproved";
?>

<p><?php echo "You have ".$newAppsCount." new applications."?></p>
```

The result of this code is this:

```
"You have SELECT * FROM AppsToBeApproved new applications."
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Are you actually executing the query?  That is not shown here.

Comment: You cant just interpolate MySQL statements into php strings and expect them to work, you actually need to connect to the database and fetch the results

Comment: Further more, there is no way `"You have ".$newAppsCount." new applications."` can result in the output string you have shown

Comment: @Crackertastic Thanks for the quick response, stupid me I was not even calling '$connection->query($newAppsCount);'.

Comment: @andrew I only posted the syntax that was giving me problems. I'm sorry for the confusion but I do connect to a database and the tables exists. I considered that to be standard setup procedure and irrelevant to the lines that were problematic, but I should have specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to first connect to database and execute the sql command.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "name_of_database";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

execute the command

```
$newAppsCount = "COUNT(appID) FROM AppsToBeApproved";
$result = $conn->query($newAppsCount);
```

And print the result then.

```
<p><?php echo "You have ".$result." new applications."?></p>
```

Make sure the sql command is correct.

Comment: thank you for your response. It was the query statement I was missing! Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use obect oriented approach by calling

```
  <?php echo ($db->dbQuery ("select some column from Table")); ?>
```

After that your query will show you results. Here in your caee, you are just displaying your variable assigned string.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the SQL commands and show just the results. In your code, you are just showing the variable content.

I am not on PC now, but try to search about mysqli or PDO to learn how to use SQL commands thru PHP. You will have to connect the DB first, and then query your SQL Statement to be able to show the results.

Hope this could help you.